# How to find multivariable regression equation in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, regression

I have searched stack overflow and have not found any question that really is the same as mine because none really have more than one independent variable. Basically I have an array of datapoints and I want to be able to find a regression equation for those data points. The code I have so far looks like this: (w,x,z are the independent variables and y is the dependent variable)

```
var dataPoints = [{
 "w" : 1, "x" : 2, "z" : 1, "y" : 7
}, {
 "w" : 2, "x" : 1, "z" : 4, "y" : 5
}, {
 "w" : 1, "x" : 5, "z" : 3, "y" : 2
}, {
 "w" : 4, "x" : 3, "z" : 5, "y" : 15
}];
```

I would like a function that would return a formula object like this:

```
var regressionEquation = [{
 "var" : "w", "power" : 1, "coeff" : "1.5"
}, {
 "var" : "x", "power" : 1, "coeff" : "2"
}, {
 "var" : "z", "power" : 1, "coeff" : "1"
}];
```

Is there a way to come up with a regression equation like this without using a loop to step and plug in the values? Is there a way to come up with the regression equation for powers that are more than 1? Thanks in advance.

EDIT

Many people have suggested solving a system of equations made by plugging in the powers. The problem I have with this is when there is more than enough data points to solve for a system of equations. In the examples in the question, I have 3 variables in order to solve the system of equations that people are suggesting, I would need 3 datapoints but I have 4. This leads to a problem because there is more than one solution. There are 4 possible solutions because there are 4 ways to combine the 4 equations into different groups of 3. This would leave me with 4 answers with possibly none of them the best fit to all 4 points.

Comment: Are you thinking about something like Polynomial Interpolation? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) I've written some js to do that before through operations on a Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: No I would like to find a regression equation and then extrapolate

Comment: so you have function w = ax^k1 + by^k2 + cz^k3 where you want to find a, b, c, k1, k2 and k3 that fit your data?

Comment: I want a process that will find a, b, and c. But I would like it to work for any values k1, k2 and k3. (I will have already decided these values)

Comment: This is probably better suited with a math tag.

Comment: First you need to determine the order of your function: linear, quadratic, cubic, etc. Then compose system of linear equations and solve. Depending on the data amount and the equation order, you can have from one to an infinite solutions number.

Comment: Looking for exact solutions, and thus inducing the question about which variables to use to avoid an overdetermined system, is called interpolation. Looking for an approximate solution is called regression. Regression algorithms, in general, does not require interpolation to work; they function in an entirely different way. The solution to a regression does **not**, in general, pass through **any** of the data points given (though it may).

Comment: in the expression ax^k1, a is the coeff and k1 is the power

Comment: also I could decide in advance that I would want to find a quadratic regression or cubic depending on the number of data points

Answer (score 1):

The problem as you've stated it is equivalent, under transformation, to a linear regression problem. You said in comments that you have fixed exponents `k_1`, `k_2`, and `k_3`. The transformation takes a tuple `{w, x, z ,y}` to the tuple `{w^k_1, x^k_2, z^k_2, y} = {w', x', z' ,y}`. Use linear regression on the primed variables to get your coefficients.

For example, if `k_1 = 2`, `k_2 = 3`, and `k_3 = 1`, then here's a single example of the transform:

```
{"w" : 4, "x" : 3, "z" : 5, "y" : 15} 
==> {"w*" : 16, "x*" : 27, "z*" : 5, "y" : 15}
```

This is just a special case of how you convert a [polynomial regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regressions) problem into a linear regression one. In your case the polynomial forms you are considering are particularly simple.

Use any JavaScript library you like to solve the linear regression problem; there are a number of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think if it is the case that there are four equations and only 3 variables (As you already determined the powers, plugin and make it a linear equation), the linear equation is over complete, and there does not exist an exact answer that will satisfy all four equations.

What you can do is to minimize the residual error and get a best approximation.

Assume you have coefficients a b and c for the w x and z,

define matrix

```
M=[w1,x1,z1;w2,x2,z2;w3,x3,z3;w4,x4,z4].
```

and define the vector

```
v=[a;b;c],
```

define vector

```
r=[y1;y2;y3;y4].
```

Then the problem is

```
M*v=r solve v.
```

**1.** If rank(M)>variable number, you have to minimize the residual error

```
||M*v-r||_2.
```

Since this is convex, take derivative on it and make it zero:

```
M^T*M*v-M^T*r=0 => v=(M^T*M)\M^T*r.
```

(M^T*M)\M^T is MP-inverse of M, if rank(M)>variable number, then (M^T*M) is inversible.

**2.** If the rank(M)<=variable number, you can get infinitely many exact solution to the equation.

```
M*v=r.
```

Let singular value decomposition of M:

```
M=U*S*V^T,
```

then

```
v=V*S^-1*U^T*r
```

is one of the solutions.

V*S^-1*U^T is pseudo inverse of M.

If you use a linear algebra library, it is very easy to get closed form solution without iterating. http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/

Comment: If the first case http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/api/matrix.html#inverse can already solve. But if the second case, I didn't see any javascript library that can return a pseudo inverse. Maybe this library http://www.numericjs.com/ can help because it can compute svd of a matrix, and you can get pseudo inverse using U S and V.

Comment: I don't truly understand all of the math used in the explanation what I understand is that in the first case(which is the only one I care for) in order to come up with the solution I would need to use to library you provided to find the inverse of the M and then find that * r using that library. Am I correct?

Comment: I tried this and it caused an error because M is not inversible because it is not a square

Comment: No it is not inverse of M, it is MP-inverse of M, v=inverse(transpose(M)*M)*transpose(M)*r; because transpose(M)*M is square, and in your case full rank, it is inversible.

Comment: If your matrix M is not too big, this closed form solution would be very fast.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using least squares for getting a linear equation.
Further, you could use non-linear least squares, given that you
know in advance the function you want to fit.

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares)

There are several links for linear LS in javascript and you can 
probably adapt these to 3 dimensions (e.g. http://dracoblue.net/dev/linear-least-squares-in-javascript/159/ from a quick Google search). For the non-linear
case it would need some more work though.

Comment: The way I understood the link that you posted it would not work for multiple variables which is a major problem

Comment: Well, it can work for any number of variables or any function (see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Solving_the_least_squares_problem) -- the thing is that it is mostly used for y=ax+b, so most of the code you'll find will be targeting this type of function. For the linear case with multiple variables see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#The_general_problem. But generally, for non-linear problems you'll probably have to work out some math by yourself.

Comment: Edit/Addition: Since, however, the system is over-determined, it's probably the way to go.

Comment: The problem really is that I don't know how to do this math