# regression coefficient using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, regression

I'm trying to find out the regression coefficient in multiple linear regression.I'm using numpy module for this.I have dependant and independent values.what I've tried is given below

```
import numpy as np
y = [5.4,6.3,6.5,6.2,8.1,7.9,6.7,6.8,4.9,5.8]
X = [[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,   1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

b = y * X.T * np.linalg.inv(X*X.T)
print(b)
```

but it is giving an error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/proj/new5.py", line 14, in <module>
b = y * X.T * np.linalg.inv(X*X.T)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'T'
```

please help me to do this.

Comment: whats `T`? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array can not be initialized like that.

you should use np.array

```
y = np.array([5.4,6.3,6.5,6.2,8.1,7.9,6.7,6.8,4.9,5.8])
```

then the T attribute will be there.

For numpy array, you can not use * to multiply, coz * is for element-wise multiplication.

If you are multiplying with matrix, like y * X.T should be written as y.dot(X.T)

**Read this page about the difference in use of array and matrix in numpy.**

[Link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935)

=====================================================

So you can get the best solution using the pseudo inverse:

if the svd of X^T is:

```
X^T = U*S*V^T ([compact svd][1])
```

Then:

```
b = V*S^-1*U^T*y
```

Here b and y are both column vector.

if you want them to be row vector, then just take transpose on both sides.

Comment: @in Lin I tried this,but its giving  ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10) (10,17)

Comment: I tried following code                                           b = y.dot(X.T) * np.linalg.inv(X.dot(X.T))  This time its giving   raise LinAlgError, 'Singular matrix'
LinAlgError: Singular matrix

Comment: @naz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368805/how-to-find-multivariable-regression-equation-in-javascript/13548846#13548846

Comment: @naz I posted a answer to the linear equation problem. In your case, the variable number is 17, however, your matrix rank is smaller or equal to 10. You have infinitely many solutions, thus you should use pseudo inverse approach.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing.Why its giving 17 sets of 17 regression coefficients?

Comment: don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: I tried b = y.dot(X.T) * np.linalg.pinv(X.dot(X.T)) its giving array of 17 lists,each containing 17 values.What's that mean?

Comment: The * should be replaced with dot for matrix multiplication.

Comment: I was working for 3 days behind this,At last I got it because of you, Thank you very much.

Comment: @naz: Given that Min Lin has helped you solve the problem, it would be good if you could tick Min Lin's answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
y = np.matrix([[1,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,5,4,5,4,5,4,5,6,5,4,5,4,3,4]])

x = np.matrix([
     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
     [4,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,7,4,8,9,8,8,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5],
     [4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,8,7,8,7,8,7,8,7,7,7,7,7,6,5],
     [4,1,2,5,6,7,8,9,7,8,7,8,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,4,4,4]
     ])

b = y * x.T * np.linalg.inv(x*x.T)
```

Result:

```
>>> b
matrix([[ 1.57044377, -0.0617812 ,  0.23596693,  0.24238522]])
```

I tried applying the above to your data, but I get singular matrix error:

```
    raise LinAlgError, 'Singular matrix'
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

So it appears that some variables in your `X` are perfectly correlated.